# Опубликовать локальные файлы в приложение heroku

Tags: heroku, deploy

Есть приложение на платформе heroku.

Приложение соединено с github репозиторием.

В репозитории не хранятся локальные файлы с ключами и прочей конфигурацией.

Как опубликовать в приложение heroku локальный файл, которого нет в репозитории?

Нашел решение через переменные среды, но оно не подходит, т.к. в локальном конфиге есть некое подобие шаблонов, которые сложно хранить в переменных среды.

Comment: Я делал бота и закунил в Heroku, добавил все необходимое с ботом и включил локальные сервер на vs code и перебросил все что было в папке в heroku ,честно это было давненько ну надеюсь кинуть вам фрагмент чтоб вы поняли

Comment: @ГорМанучарян, локальный сервер имеется ввиду локальный гит репозиторий?

Comment: Да, там на видео он бота загружал через гит все делал

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ven-pqwk3ec&t=248s вот начните смотреть 4.30 он там бота кидает, он там логинится и начинает через гит все делать

Comment: да, я видел как через гит туда закитывают все, но у меня репозиторий на гитхабе, и я не могу там держать локальные файлы